# How can i change default error arabic Text message in form_builder_validators

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-form-builder

I want to change this text to my custom text in all form builder validators in the app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGhqx.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package [form_builder_validators](https://pub.dev/packages/form_builder_validators)
which you can pass your custom error text like this

```
FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: "hello world")
```

here an example

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FormBuilder(
                key: _formKey,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                child:  FormBuilderTextField(
                  name: 'email',
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                  validator:  FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: "hello world"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```